# Difference between "marginal variance" and "true variance"?

Tags: definition

[This question is not about solving a mathematical problem, but about definitions; please tell me if there is a better forum to ask it.]

In a paper I am reading, the author writes:

> ...the sole reason for minimizing the **marginal variance** instead of **true variance** was that...

What is the difference between both definitions?